# Issue with setting up Open Scene graph (OSG)

Tags: installation, 13.04

I am currently trying to build and install OSG. I have installed all the dependencies however when I go to cmake the OSG folder i get the following cmake error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
```

How is this library not set?

I am attempting to install on an ubuntu 13.04 in an Oracle virtual box.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to build paraview.
At the time I was uisng cmake 2.8.3. I just could not workaround
this error no matter what I tried.

Anyway eventually this problem went away when I replaced cmake 2.8.3
with 2.8.11.2!